# two routers in one network; one as gateway, one as DHCP server

Tags: networking, router

My ISP changed their network configuration and now my home setup is not working anymore. I had one Asus router which features like QoS and parental control, my physical network consists of UTP, powerlan and wifi.

In the new setup I'm required to run a new router (functionally crippled) to handle IPTV and telephone, but I would still like to run all my LAN traffic through my Asus for the additional functionality it provides. Not a problem I thought, until it turned out that the IPTV units are required to be connected directly to the new router. Which means all other systems using the powerlan (a.o. a Wifi Access Point) also bypass the Asus. Parental control is useless.

Is there anyway I can setup the new router to only function as a gateway, and let everything go though the Asus?

This setup did not work: internet <-> [extern IP] newrouter [192.168.2.254] <-> [192.168.2.253] Asus [192.168.2.1] <-> LAN [192.168.2.100-199]

- The new router has 254 as its LAN IP
- The Asus has a static WAN ip of 253, and its LAN IP to 1 (with 254 as the gateway).
- DHCP hands out IP configs with 1 as the gateway

Theoretically this means any LAN device getting an IP will send to the Asus on IP 1, it forwards that via 253 to the new router at 254, which pushes it out to the internet.

But alas. **Any suggestions if this can be made to work?**

- I cannot change the subnet on the new router, it is blocked to 255.255.255.0.
- I do want wat to run switches everywhere to setup a VLAN.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on `Super User`.

Comment: Ok, I did not know that.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a different subnet for your asus router. 
e.g. use the `192.168.2.1` address for your asus router and configure DHCP to hand out IPs of that network (`192.168.2.x`). Then configure your new Router to have the IP `192.168.1.1`.
Now add a static route from your asus router to your new router and the other way round. That way every device in the `192.168.2.x` network has to go through your asus router.

Of course that does only work if you can configure routes on your new router.

Comment: Yes, that was my initial setup. But the problem is that part of my network (powerlan) needs to directly be connected to the new router (because the TV boxes need to be), and that part bypasses the Asus.